# Does MaaS have any log?

Tags: juju, log, maas

Using following articles,

1. [Testing MAAS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/TestingMAAS)
2. [Ubuntu Cloud Infrastructure with MAAS and Juju](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_MAAS_and_Juju)

I tried to setup Ubuntu Server 12.04's private cloud in a virtual environment provided by KVM and virt-install.

I resolved several issues but now, this one is fooling me for several days :(

> Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 409 CONFLICT

I get this answer in result of

> juju bootstrap

I know that this means that the MaaS cannot allocate the needed nodes to bootstrap juju; but I checked all configurations several times. I also did not get any error while above articles processings! I've been added needed nodes and accepted them and now they're in commissioning state. My non-admin username in MaaS matches who runs juju and it's ssh key also matches.

I doubted the maas-dhcp server, so I even added a live-cd virtual machine and I saw in MaaS's syslog that it successfully can assign a new IP to the new virtual machine. I really do not know what problem can be :(

Anyway, does MaaS log anything about why it cannot allocate needed nodes?! if so, where is it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logs are located in `/var/log/maas/` on your MaaS server.

The main log to check is `/var/log/maas/maas.log`